# G.726 (ADPCM): описание алгоритма

Tags: c#, delphi, c++

Здравствуйте.
Возможно кто-нибудь работал с кодеком G.726 (ADPCM). ITU-T Recommendation G.726. 40, 32, 24, 16 kbit/s ADAPTIVE DIFFERENTIAL PULSE CODE MODULATION (ADPCM) изучал, пытался писать на delphi, но что-то не выходит. Может не правильно понимаю с английского. 
Если есть у кого-нибудь краткое описание алгоритма или ссылка на понятный ресурс. Ищу больше месяца, но никак не найду.
Заранее спасибо.